# Missing inference.py error when creating Sagemaker Endpoint for PyTorch model

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to deploy a PyTorch model to a Sagemaker model endpoint using `boto3`'s [CreateModel](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateModel.html), [CreateEndpointConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateEndpointConfig.html) and [CreateEndpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateEndpoint.html) but it is fails on creating because of this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/bin/torch-model-archiver", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(generate_model_archive())
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/model_archiver/model_packaging.py", line 59, in generate_model_archive
    package_model(args, manifest=manifest)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/model_archiver/model_packaging.py", line 37, in package_model
    model_path = ModelExportUtils.copy_artifacts(model_name, **artifact_files)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/model_archiver/model_packaging_utils.py", line 150, in copy_artifacts
    shutil.copy(file, model_path)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 245, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/conda/bin/torch-model-archiver", line 8, in <module> sys.exit(generate_model_archive()) File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/model_archiver/model_packaging.py", line 59, in generate_model_archive package_model(args, manifest=manifest) File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/model_archiver/model_packaging.py", line 37, in package_model model_path = ModelExportUtils.copy_artifacts(model_name, **artifact_files) File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/model_archiver/model_packaging_utils.py", line 150, in copy_artifacts shutil.copy(file, model_path) File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 245, in copy copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks) File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/ml/model/code/inference.py'
```

**I'm stumped on this because I specified a [pre-built inference image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg-ecr-paths/ecr-eu-west-1.html#pytorch-eu-west-1.title) when creating my model, so I didn't think an `inference.py` script was necessary.**

To reproduce (Python, in Sagemaker notebook), I'm just calling the three boto3 sagemaker APIs, and using prebuilt inference image `763104351884.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pytorch-inference:1.8.0-cpu-py3`:

```
import boto3
from sagemaker import get_execution_role
import sagemaker

sagemaker = boto3.client("sagemaker")
model_name = "model"
model_endpt_config_name = "model_cfg"
model_endpt_name = "model_endpt"

sagemaker.create_model(
    ModelName=model_name,
    PrimaryContainer={
        "Image": "763104351884.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/pytorch-inference:1.8.0-cpu-py3",
        "Mode": "SingleModel",
        "ModelDataUrl": "s3:://<my-personal-bucket>/model.tar.gz",
        "Environment": {
            "SAGEMAKER_CONTAINER_LOG_LEVEL": "20",
            "SAGEMAKER_REGION": region,
        },
    },
    ExecutionRoleArn=get_execution_role(),
)
sagemaker.create_endpoint_config(
    EndpointConfigName=model_endpt_config_name,
    ProductionVariants=[
        {
            "VariantName": "Prod",
            "ModelName": model_name,
            "InitialInstanceCount": 1,
            "InstanceType": "ml.c5.large",
            "InitialVariantWeight": 1,
        },
    ]
)
sagemaker.create_endpoint(
    EndpointName=model_endpt_name,
    EndpointConfigName=model_endpt_config_name
)
```

My `model.tar.gz` only contains a single `model.pt` file. Is it that a `code/inference.py` script is always required in this case?

I know it's a long question but documentation/tutorials are very hard to find for this, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!